# pass source object to TryUpdateModelAsync

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I have a controller post action which has two parameters, and I want to use the first to update the database using TryUpdateModelAsync (the second is some rendering parameter).

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(Amendment amendment, string format)
{
     var amendmentToUpdate = await _context.Amendments
                .SingleOrDefaultAsync(a => a.Id == amendment.Id);

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            try
            {
                await TryUpdateModelAsync<Amendment>(
                    amendmentToUpdate,
                    "",
                    a => a.Title, a => a.Date);

                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                ...
```

It seems that the TryUpdateModelAsync finds the controller context and automatically updates these fields, but since I'm passing in two parameters, it doesn't know that it should take these from `amendment`. Is there a way to pass in the "source object" to `TryUpdateModelAsync`?

Comment: Mark it as `Edit([FromBody]Amendment amendment, string format)`

Comment: I found I can also just do `amendmentToUpdate.Title = amendment.Title` ...